# HTTPWebRequest GET request causing SSL connection issue

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest

I am trying to connect to a RESTful API and when I access the URL from my browser I get an error stating I am missing headers which is what I was expecting to get. When I connect to the same URL using the below code I get an error stating "The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send. ---> System.IO.IOException: Authentication failed because the remote party has closed the transport stream". If I use the same code and change the URL to Google.com it works fine and to add to the mystery the connection I make to the API URL from my browser will generate an entry in the Apache logs on the API server, but the below code doesn't. Does anyone have any ideas why I would get that error?

```
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("HTTPS://URL.COM");

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.Method = "GET";

        string html = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
            string responseString = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();



            Response.Write(responseString);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write(ex.ToString());
        }
```

UPDATE: I tried using HttpClient and got the same results:

```
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri("https://url.com/");

        // Add an Accept header for JSON format.
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
            new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

        HttpResponseMessage response = client.GetAsync("v1/person").Result;

        if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            Response.Write(response);

        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write(response);
        }
```

UPDATE 2: The below line of code seems to fix the problem. I am awaiting confirmation now. I am still a little baffled why this was required though.

```
    System.Net.ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = System.Net.SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;
```

Comment: It may be that the server only accepts TLS 1.1 or 1.2. Unless you configure the `ServicePointManager`, you will be trying to connect with SSL. I'd suggest using `HttpClient` instead of `HttpWebRequest` if it is an option.

Comment: I updated my original post. HttpClient generated the same error.

Comment: The SSL Cert on the application server uses TLS 1.2 AES_128_CBC with HMAC-SHA1 and the API application server uses TLS 1.2 AES_128_GCM with ECDHE_RSA.

Comment: Your fix was what CrowCoder was referring to. The target seems to require TLS1.2, so adding that line explicitly says your _client_ should (only) use it. Off topic but similar: ran into same with Paypal API (they _require_ TLS 1.2)

Comment: Update 2 fixed it for me.